# Archlinux installation problem

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation

I've used 2 usb's, both livelinuxusb and unetbootin, and tried multiple reinstalls and formats. Whenever I try and install Archlinux x86_64 it unpacks the kernel and the says "0.000 fast tsc calibration failed" after that the computer runs but the screen turns off.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19064/got-a-black-screen-while-booting-archlinux-installation-program

Comment: I checked that link and this is a different problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Got a black screen while booting archlinux installation program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19064/got-a-black-screen-while-booting-archlinux-installation-program)

Comment: The OP declared that link a "different problem" 4 years ago, and there are no new answers in the meantime. Voting with the OP to leave open for now.

Comment: Ah! Now I see the OP self-answered here. I meant to say “no new answers in the proposed duplicate “

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot that I asked this question until someone else submitted an answer. My fault for not updating with the actual answer but better late than never. The real problem was that the PC I was trying to install on had misconfigured BIOS options. Somehow the BIOS was trying to read the CD/DVD drive and the HDD as a single RAID array. This didn't worked and so it gave a cryptic error when trying to install Arch. I turned off RAID entirely in the BIOS and my install worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `Unetbootin` or any other program to burn the image on a USB drive. You can just use the `dd` command in a Linux system.

Run the following command, replacing the `/dev/sdx` with your drive, e.g., `/dev/sdb`.
(Do not append a partition number, so *do not* use something like `/dev/sdb1`)

```
dd bs=4M if=/path/to/archlinux.iso of=/dev/sdx status=progress oflag=sync
```

By doing this, the system will boot like a burned CD, because `dd` burned the ISO file to a USB drive.

If you are using Windows systems you can use [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/?locale), for example.
It is easier than `Unetbootin` and you can burn images on a `GPT` partition and `UEFI` mode.

Read more on [Archlinux pre installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media). There is a topic on BIOS and UEFI bootable USB.

Comment: The question wasn't about how to burn an image it was about a specific error message.