# Linux installation failure: black rectangle

Tags: linux, system-installation, grub2, display

I want to install Kali Linux (but the issue also appears for Debian). I created a live USB stick with the distribution. When reaching the splash screen I can select live execution and have a live version of Kali linux running without issue. When I select "install" (in graphical or text mode), a black rectangle appears and the installation does not appear to start. However with the speech synthesis, the black rectangle appears but I can hear the voice giving instructions to select the language. I suppose therefore that the problem comes from the display?
I tried changing the command by adding `nomodeset` like in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19064/got-a-black-screen-while-booting-archlinux-installation-program) but I am not sure how to exactly write the command.

The pc is a HP laptop Elitebook 840 G4 with an Intel HD Graphics 620 graphic card.

How can I install a linux distribution when facing this issue?

[image: error]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the boot menu, I was selecting my usb stick. I didn't saw that there was another option called "**legacy USB**". Selecting that option solved the issue.